# mpic++ undefined reference to typeinfo for tbb::task

Tags: c++, tbb

I am trying to use `std::sort(std::execution::par,x.begin(),x.end())` ; so I need to tell the compiler that c++17 or c+20 should be used.
In my make file I wrote:
`CXX_COMPILE=mpic++ -std=c++17 -fopenmp -Wall -Wextra -fPIC $(OPT_DEBUG) CXX_LINK=mpic++ -fPIC $(EXTRAFLAGS) $(OPT_DEBUG)`
I got the error that:
`fatal error: tbb/blocked_range.h: No such file or directory`
so I installed tbb and modified CXX_COMPILE to be:
`CXX_COMPILE=mpic++ -ltbb -std=c++17 -fopenmp -Wall -Wextra -fPIC $(OPT_DEBUG)`
Compiling this gave me bunch of errors telling:

```
undefined reference to `typeinfo for tbb::task' 
internal::allocate_continuation_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const'
tbb::internal::allocate_child_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const'
```

Is anything wrong in Makefile?

Comment: Could be that your `-ltbb` appears too early on the command line.

Comment: @Marc Glisse sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: `mpic++ files -ltbb` good, `mpic++ -ltbb files` bad.

Comment: It seems to be a code specific issue. Can, you plz provide us with a reproducer